# Inherit initialize method in TypeScript

Tags: inheritance, typescript, initialization

Sometimes I want to run some code after the class has been instantiated and all constructors have been called. In order to do this I call a `initialize` method on the last line of the `constructor` method.

This doesn't work when using inheritance because the `initialize` method will be called before the last `constructor` has been called. Simply calling the initialize function in all inherited classes and we will end up with multiple calls.

### Example

```
class A {
    
    public get static() {
        return Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor;
    }
    
    constructor() {
        console.log('constructor A');
        this.initialize();
    }
    
    public initialize() {
        console.log('initialize A');
    }
}
    
class B extends A {
    
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log('constructor B');
    }
    
    public initialize() {
        console.log('initialize B');
    }
}

console.info('instantiate A');
var a = new A();

console.info('instantiate B');
var b = new B();
```

### Result

[image: Result 1]

### Possible solution

I found a way to call the initializer if the called class is equal to the class passed to a `constructed` method. One downside of this is that the constructed method always has to be called in order for the initialize method to be called.

```
class A {

    public get static() {
        return Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor;
    }
    
    constructor() {
        console.log('constructor A');
        this.constructed(A);
    }
    
    public constructed(type:any) {
        if (type === this.static) {
            this.initialize();
        }
    }
    
    public initialize() {
        console.log('initialize A');
    }
}

class B extends A {

    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log('constructor B');
        this.constructed(B);
    }
    
    public initialize() {
        console.log('initialize B');
    }
}

console.info('instantiate A');
var a = new A();

console.info('instantiate B');
var b = new B();
```

### Result

[image: Result 2]

## Question

Is there a better way to run code after all construction has been done than the example above?

I've also thought about:

```
var a = new A();
a.initialize();
```

But I found you simply don't want to do that in many cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a create method ([Creational pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern)).

If initialize() needs to run after the constructor of B it's likely that A is somewhat dependent on what happens in B's constructor so it might be that inheritance is already 'broken'. Dealing with that problem outside of inheritance should therefore be appropriate.

Here is an example:

```
class A {

    constructor() {
        console.log('constructor A');
    }

    public initialize() {
        console.log('initialize A');
    }

    static create<T>():T{
        var o =  <any>new this;
        o.initialize();
        return o;
    }
}

class B extends A {

    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log('constructor B');
    }

    public saySomething(){
        console.log('Woof!');
    }
}

var b:B = B.create<B>(); 
// "constructor A"
// "constructor B"
// "initialize A"
console.log( b instanceof A ); // true
b.saySomething(); // Woof!
```